# How to get an InputDialog box to accept two values successively

Tags: java, swing

```
package javaapplication4;
import javax.swing.*;

public class JavaApplication4 {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        int num1;

        num1 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a value"));
            if(num1<50 && num1>100)
                System.out.println("value is correct");
            else 
                System.out.println("value is incorrect");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1**

You can repeat the operation 2 times like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 0, n = 2;//repeat n time
    while (i < n) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        int num1;

        num1 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a value"));
        if (num1 < 50 && num1 > 100) {
            System.out.println("value is correct");
        } else {
            System.out.println("value is incorrect");
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

**Solution 2**

You can use an array to store your values and check them later for example :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 0, n = 2;

    // TODO code application logic here
    int num1[] = new int[n];

    while (i < n) {
        num1[i] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please value " + (i+1)));
        i++;
    }
    if (num1[0] < 50 && num1[1] > 100) {
        System.out.println("value is correct");
    } else {
        System.out.println("value is incorrect");
    }
}
```

This will ask you for the n value, in your case will ask you to enter 2 values so it will stored in your array, then you can check this values of array.

**EDIT**

You have to use a separator and you can split with this separator for example your input should look like this :

```
6999,888
--1---2
```

so when you split with `,` `String[] spl = res.split(",");` you will get an array of String like `[6999,888]`, then you can use this two value to make your condition :

```
int v1 = Integer.parseInt(spl[0]);//convert String to int
int v2 = Integer.parseInt(spl[1]);//convert String to int
```

So your program should look like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String res = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a value separated with , :");
    String[] spl = res.split(",");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(spl));
    //you have to make some check to avoid any problem
    int v1 = Integer.parseInt(spl[0]);
    int v2 = Integer.parseInt(spl[1]);

    if (v1 < 50 && v2 > 100) {
        System.out.println("value is correct");
    } else {
        System.out.println("value is incorrect");
    }
}
```

**Edit2**

You can show your result in JOptionPane like this :

```
if (v1 < 50 && v2 > 100) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "value is correct");
} else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "value is incorrect");
}
```

**EDIT3**

To get the max you have to check it like this :

```
if (v1 > v2) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "larger value is : " + v1);
} else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "larger value is : " + v2);
}
```

Or in one line you can use :

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "larger value is : " + (v1 > v2 ? v1 : v2));
```

Comment: thank you for your assistance, however this does not solve my issue, unfortunately i believe it was an error on my part, i need the input dialog box to accept the values as ( 55 74) then determine if they fall within the specified range and finally shows the larger of the two numbers in a message dialog box, thank you for your assistance so far

Comment: so you need two Fields, field for the 1st value and field for the second in one JOptionPane @SaienLakshuman or what exactly?

Comment: i need one field to accept two separate numbers one after the other like this [55, 99], then determine if the are within the range of greater than 50 but less than 100 then determine which of the two is larger

Comment: aaaahhh ok, so you can use a separator then you can split with this separator i will give you an example @SaienLakshuman

Comment: i think so, sorry for the trouble, this is my first time working with java

Comment: any ideas how to do the next part... check which of the two is higher and display the result in a message dialog box

Comment: and also if you can please help me out by displaying this                             if (v1 < 50 && v2 > 100) {
        System.out.println("value is correct");
    } else {
        System.out.println("value is incorrect");
    }                                                                                                              result in a message dialog box please that will be greatly appreciated

Comment: thank you so much, one more thing, if its not too much trouble... the part about determining the larger of the two and displaying it in a message dialog box e.g. (55,66) the larger of the two is 66